# Using mongodb field values in update to get an index of an external array?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

A novice mongodb developer here. I'm trying to write an update query where I search for stocks of certain products and decrease the quantities based on how many products are being sold. I have a products list which is a list of objects, it contains the products that are being sold.

```
products= [
  {
    product: "*some product id*",
    quantity: "*some quantity*"
  }
]
```

I extract product ids from the above list into a productIds list.
And below is how my query looks like. I have realized I can't pass "$product" [a field of the stock] into the indexof(), is there a way to handle this using update with an aggregation pipeline? If not what other options do I have ? I have searched the documentation but couldn't find anything helpful.

```
Stock.updateOne(
      {
        product: { $in: productIds },
        quantity: { $gt: 0 },
      },
      [
        {
          $set: {
            newQuantity: {
              $subtract: [
                "$quantity",
                products[productIds.indexOf("$product")].quantity,
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Do you have the possiblite to save the list of products in a collection? it will be easier to use lookup to realize your substraction

Comment: The list of products is part of the `Orders` collection. Once an order is created in db, I then need to readjust the stocks and that is what this query is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- `$reduce` to find the quantity to subtract
- listQuantity will be the that quantity, product is compared with the product of the list, and if match, we get the quantity (as reduce result)
- instead of `"input": [{"product":1, "quantity":3}, {"product":2, "quantity":4}]` use `"input": YOUR_JS_ARRAY_VARIABLE`
- and then subtract this quantity from the previous one
- productIds must be only the `[1,2]` in this example

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70473150-m)

```js
Stock.update(
{
  "product": { "$in": productIds },
  "quantity": { "$gt": 0 },
}
,
[{"$set":
  {"listQuantity":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":
     [{"product":1, "quantity":3}, {"product":2, "quantity":4}],
     "initialValue":-1,
     "in":
     {"$cond":
      [{"$and":
        [{"$eq":["$$value", -1]},
         {"$eq":["$$this.product", "$product"]}]},
       "$$this.quantity", "$$value"]}}}}},
 {"$set":
  {"quantity":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$eq":["$listQuantity", -1]}, "$quantity",
     {"$subtract":["$quantity", "$listQuantity"]}]},
   "listQuantity":"$$REMOVE"}}])
```

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution, you should mention changing the `$product` which generally is an objectId to a string for comparison in `$and`, otherwise it worked great(I used `{ $toString: "$product" }`). I'm wondering how performant is this compared to iterating the products list and making an update query for each product individually ?

Comment: pipeline updates are slower than normal updates, at least one time that i benchmarked those it seemed like that, but sending 1 query instead of multiple i think its way more important, for atomicity and for performance (for example here each query will do travel to server(you could batch to reduce this time), get ready to execute, use index(or collection scan) to find the product, load document to memory etc). 
but still best way is to benchmark it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the dataset of the Order Collection that I used to write my query

```
{
  "name" : "Order 2",
  "products" : [
    {"idProduct" : "61c5ec036d9383e03e62d8ae" , "quantity" : 6 },
    {"idProduct" : "61c5ebee6d9383e03e62d8ac" , "quantity" : 2 } ]
}
```

Here is my aggregate on the Order Collection to update products on the Product Collection

```
[{$unwind: {
  path: "$products"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'Product',
  localField: 'products.idProduct',
  foreignField: '__id',
  as: 'productsToAdjust'
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$productsToAdjust"
}}, {$set: {
  "productsToAdjust.quantity":  { $subtract :["$productsToAdjust.quantity","$products.quantity"] }
}}, {$replaceRoot: {
  newRoot: "$productsToAdjust"
}}, {$merge: {
  into: 'Product',
  on: '__id',
  whenMatched: 'merge',
  whenNotMatched: 'fail'
}}]
```